# Interface Builder Build Failure in mixed Swift/Objective-C Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, interface-builder, bridging-header

I have a fairly complex situation that will be better with help.

- This is an iOS app with mixed Swift and Objective - C.
- Objective C classes subclass from Objective C classes only.
- I have one Swift class named SettingsViewController.swift that extends from a Swift library class called QuickTableViewController. QuickTableViewController is a framework installed via Carthage. https://github.com/bcylin/QuickTableViewController.

After I set this up, I receive a build error when navigating to "Main.storyboard". I can still run the app, but I can't see my IBDesignables in the Interface Builder.  The build error shows in the output detail (Figure 1), and shows "Failed" in the main status pane - with a warning icon  (Figure 2).

*Figure 1*
[image: Failure message Figure 1]

*Figure 2*
[image: Failure message Figure 2]

The failure trace leads to the bridging header import line in my ***.m Objective-C files** :

```
#import "TestApp-Swift.h"
```

So.. I have an objective-c view controller (*.m) that creates the SettingsViewController.swift view, but it throws this error. I am not subclassing from swift, just using the bridging header in a view.m and a project that has a swift view that sub-classes a swift library class.

Here is how I create SettingsViewController for navigation in my .m file:

```
UIViewController *settingsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsTableViewController"];

if (settingsVC) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:(UIViewController*)settingsVC animated:true];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR, Could not segue to Settings Table View.");
}
```

Any help will make me happy. The Interface Builder needs to happily show my IBDesignables and keep working if I use Swift libraries for views in this mixed project.

Comment: You are probably asking too much of IBDesignable. It is good for simple things.

Comment: Is `QuickTableViewController` imported from your carthage framework correctly?

Comment: @JoGoFo yes, according to their docs. Also setup Carthage correctly.